# compact(): Undefined variable: operator - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having this error on my Laravel project. I already tried to change the version of my php but did not work.

I currently using:

```
Php version is PHP 7.3.11

Laravel version 5.5.34
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Thanks for the response.

Comment: where is your code??how can we suppose to help without anything??

Comment: Please show your code....

Comment: Click on the application frame(3) then the only Laravel will show the actual error in your code along with a certain code snippet.

Comment: where are you assign value to "operator" variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your Laravel version; latest 5.5 is 5.5.48. This was fixed some time around 5.5.41.

[laravel/framework github - [5.5] Remove undefined variable from compact #25193](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25193)

Answer (score 0):

You should degrade your php version to 7.1.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue. You should degrade your php version to 7.1.
This works for me hope it will also works for you.